# Package imports, cannot use struct from imported package

Tags: go

This is probably a noob mistake but I cannot figure this out.

In main.go I am importing a package.

```
import(
    "models/users"
)

// ...

func main() {
    r.HandleFunc("/users/list", UsersModel.List())
```

The package is stored in src/models/users

The users package looks like this:

```
package users

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

// ...

/**
 * User Model
 */
type UsersModel struct {

}

// Add methods to the UsersModel type.
func (m *UsersModel) List() {
// ...
```

When I run the code I get the following error.

> src\main.go:9: imported and not used: "models/users" src\main.go:20:
>   undefined: UsersModel

The go code appears to be valid as if I invalidate it throws an error. How do I export the UsersModel type from the users package?

Comment: UsersModel is not a var but a type in your main.go. You must have a instance of UsersModel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rand package error in Go](//stackoverflow.com/q/8231573/90527)

Answer (score 6):

You need to prefix your use of `UsersModel` with the package name `users`, like so:

```
um := users.UserModel{}
```

---

`UsersModel.List()` is also wrong: go doesn't have "static methods" or "class methods".

Comment: Just to expand on this: unless you have created an instance of `UsersModel` (i.e. `user := users.UsersModel{}`) you can't call a method. In your case, you can't reliably do that because you can't feed that into `HandleFunc` in a clear way. You would be better off making a `ListAllUsersHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` that has `user := users.UsersModel{}` and then turns the content of your `users` instance into HTML/JSON/whatever.